# Checking for phone numbers in spam filter

Tags: feature-request, spam-handling

Is it possible to edit the spam to check for phone numbers? This black magic guy who keeps spamming always uses phone numbers, is it possible to check for this and try to block him?

Comment: Checking for the words `baba ji` or `babaji` is also an option..

Answer (score 3):

Just flag as spam, there are some automatic mechanisms that will automatically block spam network-wide if enough posts are flagged and/or the users destroyed as spammers by mods.

Trying to detect phone numbers sounds like it would be too dangerous, the chance of false positives would be too high.

Comment: Depends, I think he is reusing the same ones? We can specifically block them?

Comment: @JulianStirling We *can* but it is a lot of work. For now, lets just flag them and see what the system does. SE recently got a new spam prevention system.

Comment: @Seth, what language are the checks written in? PHP? Is this the work you speak of or is getting it implemented/checking the hard part?

Comment: @JulianStirling I personally don't know. You'd have to ask the SE developers, but I rather doubt they'd tell you. Most of SE is written in C# however.

Comment: @JulianStirling The blacklist that could be used to block such phone numbers uses regular expressions. So it would certainly possible to block them, but I can almost guarantee that SE would consider this too risky. They occasionally use more drastic blacklists that could cause false positives, but only if there is a whole flood of spam. The blacklisted terms that stay for longer have to be very conservative.

Comment: Thanks, I see the issue. Flagging and cleaning is better than false positives, and it isn't like we are flooded with it.